# Crash: Can only call -[PFObject init] on subclasses conforming to PFSubclassing

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, segue

Hello I am learning Swift and I am trying to implement Parse into my app. So I have one MapView which has some annotations. Those annotation are drawn from coordinate stored in Parse database. Each coordinate tuple in Parse has come other details too like FirstName LastName and all. Now Once the user click on the DETAILS button which is present in the mapView. It takes user to a table view controller where user sees all the details pertaining to the coordinates that were visible in the mapView. Till now everything works fine. So If I have 4 annotations in map view. Then By clicking on DETAILS I am redirected to the Table view controller where I can see the details pertaining to all the coordinate/annotations present in the mapView. Now I want a functionality where user can click on the table view controller cell and I can pass on the data to another view pertaining to that particular cell. SO if in the table view controller user click on 4th cell which is belonging to one of the annotation displayed on the map view. I want that 4th cell detail to be passed to another view controller.

map view (with multiple annotations) -> tableview controller (with  multiple cells) -> view controller (pertaining to the cell the user clicked).

Problem: As soon as I click on any of the cell in table view controller so that I can see that cell's detail in another view controller My app crashes and I see error as

```
2015-11-30 21:38:42.998 LifeLine[53788:6661072] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can only call -[PFObject init] on subclasses conforming to PFSubclassing.'
```

I have put breakpoint AT PREPAREFORSEGUE METHOD in table view controller. But even before the prepareforsegue method breakpoints hits my app is already crashed. So the crash happens between -- my click on the cell and the hitting of breakpoint on prepareforsegue.

My MapViewController:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import MessageUI

class MultipleAnnotationViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
    var arrayOfPFObject: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
    var lat_ :Double = 0
    var long_ :Double = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var dispAnnotation: MKMapView!
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dispAnnotation.delegate = self
        for coordinateItem in arrayOfPFObject
        {
            let pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            self.lat_ = coordinateItem["Latitude"] as! Double
            self.long_ = coordinateItem["Longitude"] as! Double
            pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  self.lat_, longitude: self.long_)
            dispAnnotation.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)

            pointAnnotation.title =  String(coordinateItem["FirstName"]) + "  " + String(coordinateItem["LastName"])



            let miles = 10.0
            let scalingFactor =  abs(( cos ( 2*M_PI*pointAnnotation.coordinate.latitude/360.0  ) ) )
            var span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0, longitudeDelta: 0)
            span.latitudeDelta = miles/69.0
            span.longitudeDelta = miles/(scalingFactor * 69.0)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(pointAnnotation.coordinate, span)
            [ self.dispAnnotation.setRegion(region, animated: true)]
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "TableView"
        {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController

            controller.arrayOfPFObject = arrayOfPFObject
        }
        if segue.identifier == "TableView2"
        {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ChecklistViewController

            controller.arrayOfPFObject = arrayOfPFObject
        }

    }


    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation)
            else
        {
            return nil }
        let identifier = "com.domain.app.something"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if annotationView == nil
        {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView?.pinTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

My TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ChecklistViewController: UITableViewController
{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

 var arrayOfPFObject: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return arrayOfPFObject.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
            "ChecklistItem", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
        print(arrayOfPFObject.count)
            print(indexPath.row)
            let coordinateItem = arrayOfPFObject[indexPath.row]

            label.text = String(coordinateItem["Address"])
        return cell

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    {
 if segue.identifier == "call"
  {
  let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! CallEmailViewController
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell( sender as! UITableViewCell)
    {
        controller.itemToEdit = arrayOfPFObject[indexPath.row]
          }

 }

   }  
}
```

My View Controller which I where I want to show detail of clicked Cell.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class CallEmailViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var itemToEdit: PFObject = PFObject()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mail()  //print(arrayOfPFObject.count)

    }

    func mail()
    {
        print("")
    }
}
```

Below is table view image. As soon as I click on any of the table view I get the error.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change var itemToEdit: PFObject = PFObject() to

```
var itemToEdit: PFObject?
```

Comment: that gives me error : 
 Cannot convert value of type 'PFObject!.Type' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<PFObject>.Type') to specified type 'PFObject'

Comment: I have put breakpoint in the override segue method in Tableview Controller . Even before the segue breakpoint hits my app crashes.

Comment: still the error is there :  Cannot convert value of type 'PFObject?.Type' (aka 'Optional<PFObject>.Type') to specified type 'PFObject'

Comment: I don't think its related to that. Because I can even comment out that line which you re pointing out. But still the error persists. Even before the override prepareforseque breakpoint hits my app crashes. So It crashes in between my clicking on the cell and before reaching to the prepareforsegue method

Comment: Is it the whole source of CallEmailViewController that you posted?

Comment: It's not the whole source. It's just a sample. I need to write some logic there.

Comment: It seems that  PFObject() is not allowed, you can find out weather it exists on other places

Comment: works for me. I had `var currentUserCard = PFObject()` Xcode give me an error. After change it to `var currentUserCard: PFObject?` it works. The currentUserCard is now nil, that's what I want.